# Formatted error messages in Playground

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

Is there any way to get the Playground errors with proper indentations?
This can help read better the issue at hand.

Instead of getting one huge line:

```
(Tx {txInputs = fromList [TxIn {txInRef = TxOutRef {txOutRefId = 183d5544f89d5e0a5cfcbd8330c73a5f629925ed5f076b5a1b06e60a35147d4c, txOutRefIdx = 2}, txInType = Just ConsumePublicKeyAddress}], txCollateral = fromList [], txOutputs = [TxOut {txOutAddress = Address {addressCredential = PubKeyCredential a2c20c77887ace1cd986193e4e75babd8993cfd56995cd5cfce609c2, addressStakingCredential = Nothing}, txOutValue = Value (Map [(,Map [(\"\",100000000000)])]), txOutDatumHash = Nothing},TxOut {txOutAddress = Address {addressCredential = ScriptCredential 8c770b7ff9ed4a5df36ca914d18723596df69556597678d9872e2158, addressStakingCredential = Nothing}, txOutValue = Value (Map [(66,Map [(\"T\",1)])]), txOutDatumHash = Just 50536f27f0948527e1df0489a97781d16155f92623b8559e00e7341f2fb0f24d}], txMint = Value (Map []), txFee = Value (Map []), txValidRange = Interval {ivFrom = LowerBound NegInf True, ivTo = UpperBound PosInf True}, txMintScripts = fromList [], txSignatures = fromList [(8d9de88fbf445b7f6c3875a14daba94caee2ffcbc9ac211c95aba0a2f5711853,b129c9922646ca3d0b1fb5349ce515d4b4aca392825794478df4479182f8e2d53c5157829cf1c72628bb7b419cafd131cfcab251188af2c9e9c5064e03045d08)], txRedeemers = fromList [], txData = fromList [(50536f27f0948527e1df0489a97781d16155f92623b8559e00e7341f2fb0f24d,Datum {getDatum = Constr 0 [Constr 0 [B \"\\162\\194\\fw\\136z\\206\\FS\\217\\134\\EM>Nu\\186\\189\\137\\147\\207\\213i\\149\\205\\\\\\252\\230\\t\\194\",I 1596059101,I 100000000,B \"f\",B \"T\"],Constr 1 []]})]}) (Lovelace {getLovelace = 2000000})))" ]
```

To get more something more like:

```
Tx {
  txInputs = fromList [
    TxIn {txInRef = TxOutRef {txOutRefId = 183d5..47d4c, txOutRefIdx = 2}, txInType = Just ConsumePublicKeyAddress}
  ], 
  txCollateral = fromList [],
  txOutputs = [
      TxOut {
        txOutAddress = Address {addressCredential = PubKeyCredential a2c20c778..09c2, addressStakingCredential = Nothing},
        txOutValue = Value (Map [(,Map [(\"\",100000000000)])]),
        txOutDatumHash = Nothing
      },
```

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a pretty printer for this (yet). But you could file an issue/feature request with [plutus](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus).

Comment: Great thank you Angeman!